# arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 cross-compiling c++11

Tags: c++11, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, g++-4.7

I'm trying to compile an example using std::future with arm-linux-nueabi-g++-4.7 compiler; however, I have the following errors:

> user@user-virtual-machine:~/projects/prova$ arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7  -pthread -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
>
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> main.cpp:8:35: error: variable ‘std::packaged_task task’ has initializer but incomplete type

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong? I installed the compiler as distribution package.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    // future from a packaged_task
    std::packaged_task<int()> task([](){ return 7; }); // wrap the function
}
```

Comment: Please provide full command line invoking g++

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the same error on an ubuntu 16.04. Compiling with the following target architecture `-march=armv7-a` worked. These other architectures `armv7-r armv6zk armv6z armv6t2 armv6k` also worked (I did not try them all).

It seems for some architectures this code does not compile. I hope your board is suported! :)